How do I fix this graphics error in VST?
I have had a problem with certain VST plugins. I have a few installed, and one of the most well known in music is Xfer Serum. I installed the program as usual with Wine, it finished and I opened the synthesizer, but its interface doesn't load, it stays completely invisible and then it doesn't let me close the program. I have tried with other plugins and everything goes perfectly, but some of them also had the same problem but in comparison its interface was frozen instead of invisible, although you could continue interacting with it and the sound came out.
I think maybe it's some dependency bug or something with my integrated graphics. I really don't know what it could be, but I would need help as I have seen many people using this same program even here in Ubuntu.
It is worth mentioning that things like video games or other programs run correctly, so this generates more doubts.
